# Get value in for loop to outside loop to array?

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview

### This is my code.

---

```
          for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {

                    int valueCellIndex = 3;//assume calculate the 0th column
                    int resultCellIndex = 4;//assume result to put into the 1th column
                    var lastRow = dataGridView2.Rows[i - 1];
                    var curRow = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
                    double last = Convert.ToInt32(lastRow.Cells[valueCellIndex].Value);
                    double cur = Convert.ToInt32(curRow.Cells[valueCellIndex].Value);

                    gain = Convert.ToInt32(curRow.Cells[resultCellIndex].Value = cur - last); //

                }
          JsonArray.Add(new JsonInput(close, gain));
```

---

How to get 'gain' in for loop into JsonArray  ?

Comment: declare an array above the forloop and add elements to array inside for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `gain` variable is `int` type, you can create a `List` object to add `gain` variable value/s inside the loop. Later convert that `int`  `List`to json array.

```
List<int> gainList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
{

    int valueCellIndex = 3;//assume calculate the 0th column
    int resultCellIndex = 4;//assume result to put into the 1th column
    var lastRow = dataGridView2.Rows[i - 1];
    var curRow = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
    double last = Convert.ToInt32(lastRow.Cells[valueCellIndex].Value);
    double cur = Convert.ToInt32(curRow.Cells[valueCellIndex].Value);    
    gain = Convert.ToInt32(curRow.Cells[resultCellIndex].Value = cur - last);
    gainList.Add(gain);
}
```

To convert the list to json format you can use `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
.....
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(gainList);
```